# TinyMCE editor does not allow nesting custom elements

Tags: html, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

When I add below HTML in editor consecutively twice, the editor adds them in a nested fashion i.e, lets say I execute the following commands:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false,`<div contenteditable="false">
<div contenteditable="true">OUTER
</div>
</div>`)

tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false,`<div contenteditable="false">
<div contenteditable="true">OUTER
</div>
</div>`)
```

then the generated HTML code is nested as shown below:

```
<div>
<div contenteditable="false">
<**div** contenteditable="true">OUTER
<div contenteditable="false">
<div contenteditable="true">OUTER</div>
</**div**>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the `<div>` tags highlighted in bold, they are nesting the inner set of `<div>` tags.

Now if I run the same command with a custom element, say `<mydiv>` and `<div>` tags, as shown below:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false,`<div contenteditable="false">
<mydiv contenteditable="true">OUTER  
</mydiv>
</div>`)

tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false,`<div contenteditable="false">
<mydiv contenteditable="true">OUTER  
</mydiv>
</div>`)
```

then the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
<div contenteditable="false"><**mydiv** contenteditable="true">OUTER</**mydiv**>
<div contenteditable="false"><**mydiv** contenteditable="true">OUTER </**mydiv**></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the 1st set of highlighted `<mydiv>` tags have closed before the 2nd set of custom `<mydiv>` tag has opened.

I want my custom `<mydiv>` tag to exhibit the same behaviour like `<div>` tags.

How can I achieve this ?

I have the following configs in tinymce.init():

```
extended_valid_elements : 'mydiv[contenteditable]',
custom_elements: 'mydiv[contenteditable]',
valid_children: "mydiv[*], div[*]"

setup: (editor: tinymce.editor) => {
                editor.on('BeforeSetContent', e => {
                // Allow <div> and <mydiv> elements in editor content
                e.content = e.content.replace(/<div>/g, '<div data-mce-bogus="1">');
                e.content = e.content.replace(/<mydiv>/g, '<mydiv data-mce-bogus="1">');
                });
}
```

Fiddle to demonstrate this issue - https://jsfiddle.net/raq007/eLask6t7/33/